# STM32L011 RTC wakeup function

Tags: stm32, rtc

I have a battery-constrained device with STM32L011. Right now I am using Nucleo-32 development board. In the end I want to use suspend mode with RTC to wake up every couple of minutes. First I want the RTC to generate an interrupt using the wakeup function.

I can see in my UART log, that the RTC is running (RTC_TR is incremented), I can also see that RTC_ISR is initially 0x23 and in the next second it is 0x423, which means that WUTF flag has been set. However no interrupt occurs.

My ISR just turns a LED on and clears EXTI flag. When I do `EXTI_SWIER |= BIT17;` the interrupt fires correctly (so I guess that EXTI and NVIC are set correctly). **My problem is that even though the interrupt is enabled, RTC is running, WUTF flag is set - the interrupt does not occur.** I have no hard faults, nor resets.

This is my RTC code:

```
RCC_APB1ENR |= BIT28; //turn on power control circuit clock
PWR_CR |= BIT8; //unlock the RTC domain, set DBP in PWR_CR
RCC_CSR |= BIT0; //rurn on LSI
while ( (RCC_CSR & BIT1) == 0); //wait for LSI to be ready

RCC_CSR |=  BIT19;  //put RTC into reset
RCC_CSR &=  ~BIT19; //take it back out of reset

//RTC on, use LSI
RCC_CSR |= BIT17;
RCC_CSR &= ~BIT16;

RCC_CSR |= BIT18; //RTC enable
RTC_WPR = 0xca; //RTC unlock
RTC_WPR = 0x53;

// RTC Initialization procedure (see reference manual)
RTC_ISR |= BIT7; //set INIT bit, request RTC stop
while ((RTC_ISR & BIT6)==0); //wait for RTC to stop

ISER |= BIT2; // enable RTC IRQ in NVIC (via EXTI line)

//wakeup configuration
RTC_CR &= ~BIT10; //clear WUTE bit
while( !(RTC_ISR & BIT2 /*WUTWF*/) ){} //wait for the bit to be set
uart_puts("RTC_ISR=");
uart_puthex(RTC_ISR);
RTC_ISR |= BIT10/*WUTWF*/; //has to be set before writing to WUTR (manual 22.7.6)
RTC_WUTR = 0x9C0; //very short wakeup period
RTC_CR = BIT14 /*WUTIE*/ | BIT10 /*WUTE*/ | BIT0|BIT1 /*WUCKSEL - RTC/2 wakeup clock*/ ; //enable wakeup function and interrupt, RTC/2 clock

RTC_ISR &= ~BIT7; //start the RTC (clear INIT bit)

EXTI_IMR |= BIT17; //enable RTC alarm going through EXTI 17 line to NVIC
EXTI_EMR |= BIT17;
EXTI_RTSR |= BIT17;
```

This is my UART log (repeats approximately every second):

```
------
Hello
RTC_ISR=c7
wutr=2496
RTC_ISR=23
RTC_TR=0
RTC_CR=4403
EXTI_PR=0
wutr=2496
RTC_ISR=423
RTC_TR=1
RTC_CR=4403
EXTI_PR=0
wutr=2496
RTC_ISR=423
RTC_TR=1
RTC_CR=4403
EXTI_PR=0
wutr=2496
RTC_ISR=423
RTC_TR=2
RTC_CR=4403
EXTI_PR=0
wutr=2496
RTC_ISR=423
RTC_TR=3
RTC_CR=4403
EXTI_PR=0
wutr=2496
RTC_ISR=423
RTC_TR=4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad. RTC wakeup uses EXTI line 20, not line 17 (as RTC alarms do) - [table 53, RM0337](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/21/bd/0f/bd/1c/88/40/f0/DM00108282.pdf/files/DM00108282.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00108282.pdf). Now works fine.